# SQL to fetch MIN date + date should be greater than today

Tags: sql

I want to write SQL query to fetch next remind date, ie.  date should be min date of Remind_Date column's group by result but should be greater than today's date. Table is below-

**My_View**

| ID | column1 | remind_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 |
| 1 | 02-01-2021 | 01-01-2023 |
| 1 | 03-01-2021 | 02-01-2023 |
| 2 | 04-01-2021 | 08-01-2021 |
| 2 | 05-01-2021 | 09-01-2021 |
| 2 | 06-01-2021 | 02-01-2023 |
| 3 | 07-01-2021 | 01-01-2023 |
| 3 | 08-01-2021 | 02-01-2023 |

Expected result is below-

| ID | column1 | remind_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03-01-2021 | 01-01-2023 |
| 2 | 06-01-2021 | 02-01-2023 |
| 3 | 08-01-2021 | 01-01-2023 |

My SQL query to fetch expected result is below which requires some changes to fetch expected Remind_date.

**SELECT ID, MAX(column1), MIN(remind_date) from My_View GROUP BY ID**

Is there any possibility to make changes in select statement only around MIN(Remind_Date) to fetch desired result.

Note : Can not add where clause since it may exclude some data from the view.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also don't tag conflicting products; SQL Server and MySQL are *very* difficult RDBMS. Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Use a case expression in the MIN(), to only include future dates.

Comment: Found the solution:

SELECT ID,MAX(column1),MIN(CASE WHEN remind_date > NOW() THEN remind_date END)
FROM My_View
GROUP BY ID